# Como seleccionar un archivo con JFileChooser y renombrarlo

Tags: java

Tengo una duda con respecto a renombrar un archivo seleccionando con **JFileChoosr***, pero me a sido muy difícil hallar una respuesta a mi problema.

```
JFileChooser selecto = (JFileChooser) e.getSource();
    String comand = e.getActionCommand();

    if (comand.equals(JFileChooser.APPROVE_SELECTION)) {

        File rutaActual = selecto.getSelectedFile();

        selecto.getSelectedFile().renameTo(new File(selecto.getSelectedFile(), "nuevoNombre.jpg"));
        System.out.println("Path: " + selecto.getSelectedFile().getPath());
```

Ese es el código que tengo hasta ahora y mi intención como dije es renombrar un archivo seleccionado cualquiera,  en mi caso un archivo jpg

Cualquier ayuda sera bien recibida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De esta manera lo puedes hacer:

1. selecciona el file que quieres renombrar
2. colocale un nombre
3. renombralo.

   ```
   import javax.swing.*;
   import java.io.File;

   public class MiClase {


       public static void main(String args[]) {


           JFileChooser jfseleccionador = new JFileChooser();
           jfseleccionador.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
           int val = jfseleccionador.showOpenDialog(null);


           if (val == JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG) {
               String pathAbsoluto = jfseleccionador.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
               String directorioActual = jfseleccionador.getCurrentDirectory().getPath();

               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Directorio: " + pathAbsoluto+ "path: "+directorioActual);

               boolean isArchivoRenombrado = jfseleccionador.getSelectedFile().renameTo(new File(directorioActual + "\\text1.png"));//este ultimo puede ser una variable y que la consultes por consola o con un dialogo.

               if (isArchivoRenombrado){
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "exito al renombrar archivo");
               }

           } else if (val == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Proceso cancelado ");
           }
       }

   }
   ```